# Difference between textAlign Left and Start on a canvas 2d context?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

What is the difference between `ctx.textAlign = 'start'` and `ctx.textAlign = 'left'` when `ctx` is a a 2d context for a canvas?

Comment: sorry, can you give more information to make this a better question?  What is ctx?

Comment: @Pheonixblade9: Typically a canvas 2dContext to draw on.

Comment: @Bergi I'm aware of this, but more context is usually better :)

Comment: ctx would be the context of a canvas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `start` value does align left when you are using a LTR (left to right) browser. In RTL browsers, the `start` value aligns right.

The `start` value is preferred for content/text information, because it will display in a way preferable to the reader (depending on browser settings). It is the default value for this attribute. It is preferable to align `right` or `left` only when you're sure it won't introduce localization problems with rtl/lrt languages.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas